# Is it possible to style mobile list views?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, xslt, xml, aspx

I have been working on a task to style mobile lists views and since then, I have been unable to find a solution in terms of how I could get the views styled.
So I am starting to wonder if is it really possible to style mobile list views in SharePoint 2010.

Your feedback in this regard will be appreciated.

Many thanks,

Sepaka

Answer (score 3):

Responding to your `sharepoint-designer` tag, I'm afraid, there is no way to style mobile list views through SharePoint Designer.

You should use RenderingTemplates for this purpose, as it is described on MSDN:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb861936.aspx

This way, you'll have to deploy a custom RenderingTemplate to the `14/template/layouts/controltemplates` folder, so this can be done either manually or (a better way) with help of a SharePoint farm solution (wsp). Hence, anyway, you'll need a farm administrator privilegies for that.

Following article demonstrates a rather illustrative example of creating a RenderingTemplate for mobile list view:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms457259.aspx

You can use a bunch of [SharePoint mobile controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.mobilecontrols.aspx) in the RenderingTemplate, or even you can create your own.

Also, you can customize mobile view a bit, modifying following SPView object properties:

- [SPView.MobileItemLimit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spview.mobileitemlimit.aspx) - number of items shown on a page
- [SPView.MobileSimpleViewField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spview.mobilesimpleviewfield.aspx) - specify column, which will represent an item in mobile view

MobileItemLimit can be specified also through the view settings page:

[image: gui mobile view settings screenshot]

Comment: I was asked to answer this on Twitter, but you nailed it, Omlin.

Comment: Thanks Omlin. Very helpful. Do you know of where can I find the CSS styling used for the views or does it depent on page layouts for the display?

I wan't to change the backcolor and the way items are displayed on the list.

Example:

Item Title
      <br> Description

<!--- Where description is a column on my list. The backgroud in blue and item tiles in red --!>

Thank you again.

Comment: CSS styling is inline for OOTB mobile list views. It is implemented using SPMobilePaddedPanel and hardcoded values, like this: `<SPMobile:SPMobilePaddedPanel RunAt="Server" BackColor="#F6F6F6">`. So there are no any detached css files for that. You can ascertain yourself, just glance in `..\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\MOBILE\*.aspx` and in '..\14\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES\MobileDefaultTemplates.aspx' file.

Comment: You are the star Omlin. I can see the light now.

Comment: @Sepaka, you're exaggerating and you know this:) But anyway, flattered, thx :) Glad to see my replies help someone.

Answer (score 1):

You can style your list views using jQuery. [jQuery mobile framework](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b3/) provides rich, accessible, touch-friendly websites and apps. However, I don’t really know if it is the best way to present information. It all depends on requirements...

Here is a quick walkthrough by [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb802700.aspx) and [Overview of Mobile Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms462572.aspx), if you're pretty new to mobile pages development.

Comment: Thanks for your response FreeStyler. I will have a look at the links and get back to theforum.

Much appreciated.

http://twitter.com/Sepaka